# onSuccess of Realm.Transaction.Callback is not getting called from IntentService

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to update records in `Realm` using `executeTransaction` function but when i call this piece of code from `IntentService` , `onSuccess` of `Ream.Transaction.Callback` is not getting called automatically after calling `copyToRealmOrUpdate`.

```
final Realm realm = getRealm() ;

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {



        //some db operations and eventually calling 
        realm.
         realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(employeeList);



    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {

          // this function never gets called if 
         //the whole function is called from IntentService
          realm.close();


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {


        realm.close();

    }
});

private RealmConfiguration initalizeRealmConfig(){


        if(realmConfiguration == null)
           return  realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(mContext)
                                    .name(DB_NAME)
                                    .schemaVersion(DB_VERSION)
                                    .build();
        else return  realmConfiguration;

    }

    public Realm getRealm(){


        return Realm.getInstance(initalizeRealmConfig());

    }
```

i am using `IntentService` for background db operation and webservice calls when i call above code from Activity `onSuccess` gets called but i really dont want to call it from Activity as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think reason is that you are doing a asynchronous transaction in the IntentService, and perhaps the IntentService is closed before the result is ready. An async transaction shouldn't necessary in any case since the IntentService is running on a background thread.

Just doing the below should be the same:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
     // work
    }
});
realm.close();
```

Comment: so you mean i dont need to call it from `IntentService` ?

Comment: You do, but you don't need an async transaction inside the IntentService. Alternative you use async transactions without using the IntentService.

Comment: is there any way where i can use both IntentService and async transaction